# Can't initialize method initGeometry(gl); initLighting(gl); on class

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, renderer, opengl-es-lighting

Help me find my mistake. I make an example from book but may be author (or i)make some trouble and i cant find solve.
First class is geometry of my object

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
public class Planet {

    FloatBuffer m_VertexData;
    FloatBuffer m_NormalData;
    FloatBuffer m_ColorData;
    float m_Scale; 
    float m_Squash;
    float m_Radius; 
    int m_Stacks, m_Slices;
    public final static int SS_SUNLIGHT = GL10.GL_LIGHT0;
        public Planet(int stacks, int slices, float radius, float squash) {

        this.m_Stacks = stacks; //1
        this.m_Slices = slices; 
        this.m_Radius = radius; 
        this.m_Squash=squash;
        init(m_Stacks,m_Slices,radius,squash,"dummy");

        }

        private void init(int stacks,int slices, float radius, float squash, String textureFile) {

            float[] vertexData;

        float[] colorData; //2
        float[] normalData;
        float colorIncrement=0f;
        float blue=0f; 
        float red=1.0f;
        int numVertices=0;
        int vIndex=0;
        int cIndex=0;
        int nIndex =0;
        m_Scale=radius;
        m_Squash=squash;
        colorIncrement=1.0f/(float)stacks;//3


            m_Stacks = stacks;      
            m_Slices = slices;
            //vertices
            vertexData = new float[ 3*((m_Slices*2+2) * m_Stacks)]; //4
            //color data
            colorData = new float[ (4*(m_Slices*2+2) * m_Stacks)]; //5
            // Normalize data 
            normalData = new float [ (3*(m_Slices*2+2)* m_Stacks)]; //1
            int phiIdx, thetaIdx;
            //latitude
            for(phiIdx=0; phiIdx < m_Stacks; phiIdx++) //6
            {

                //starts at -90 degrees (-1.57 radians) goes up to +90 degrees (or +1.57 radians)
                //the first circle
                float phi0 = (float)Math.PI * ((float)(phiIdx+0) * (1.0f/(float)(m_Stacks)) - 0.5f); //7
                //the next, or second one.
                float phi1 = (float)Math.PI * ((float)(phiIdx+1) * (1.0f/(float)(m_Stacks)) - 0.5f); //8

                float cosPhi0 = (float)Math.cos(phi0); //9
                float sinPhi0 = (float)Math.sin(phi0); 
                float cosPhi1 = (float)Math.cos(phi1); 
                float sinPhi1 = (float)Math.sin(phi1);
                float cosTheta, sinTheta;
                //longitude
                for(thetaIdx=0;thetaIdx < m_Slices; thetaIdx++)
                {
                    //increment along the longitude circle each "slice"
                    float theta= (float) (-2.0f*(float)Math.PI * ((float)thetaIdx) *(1.0/(float)(m_Slices-1)));
                    cosTheta = (float)Math.cos(theta);
                    sinTheta = (float)Math.sin(theta);

                    //we're generating a vertical pair of points, such
                    //as the first point of stack 0 and the first point of stack 1 
                    //above it. This is how TRIANGLE_STRIPS work, 
                    //taking a set of 4 vertices and essentially drawing two triangles
                    //at a time. The first is v0-v1-v2 and the next is v2-v1-v3. Etc.
                    //get x-y-z for the first vertex of stack
                    vertexData[vIndex+0] = m_Scale*cosPhi0*cosTheta;    //11 
                    vertexData[vIndex+1] = m_Scale*(sinPhi0*m_Squash); 
                    vertexData[vIndex+2] = m_Scale*(cosPhi0*sinTheta);
                    vertexData[vIndex+3] = m_Scale*cosPhi1*cosTheta; 
                    vertexData[vIndex+4] = m_Scale*(sinPhi1*m_Squash); 
                    vertexData[vIndex+5] = m_Scale*(cosPhi1*sinTheta);
                    colorData[cIndex+0] = (float)red;   //12
                    colorData[cIndex+1] = (float)0f;
                    colorData[cIndex+2] = (float)blue;
                    colorData[cIndex+4] = (float)red;
                    colorData[cIndex+5] = (float)0f; 
                    colorData[cIndex+6] = (float)blue; 
                    colorData[cIndex+3] = (float)1.0;
                    colorData[cIndex+7] = (float)1.0;

                    // Normalize data pointers for lighting. 
                    normalData[nIndex + 0] = cosPhi0*cosTheta;
                    normalData[nIndex + 1] = sinPhi0; 
                    normalData[nIndex + 2] = cosPhi0*sinTheta;
                    normalData[nIndex + 3] = cosPhi1*cosTheta;
                    normalData[nIndex + 4] = sinPhi1; 
                    normalData[nIndex + 5] = cosPhi1*sinTheta;


                    cIndex+=2*4;    //13
                    vIndex+=2*3;     //14
                    nIndex+=2*3;
                }
                //  blue+=colorIncrement;   //15
                    red-=colorIncrement;
                    // create a degenerate triangle to connect stacks and maintain winding order //16
                    vertexData[vIndex+0] = vertexData[vIndex+3] = vertexData[vIndex-3]; 
                    vertexData[vIndex+1] = vertexData[vIndex+4] = vertexData[vIndex-2]; 
                    vertexData[vIndex+2] = vertexData[vIndex+5] = vertexData[vIndex-1];

                }



            m_VertexData = makeFloatBuffer(vertexData); //17 
            m_ColorData = makeFloatBuffer(colorData);
            m_NormalData = makeFloatBuffer(normalData);

        }

        protected static FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr)
        {

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length*4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); 
        FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer(); fb.put(arr);
        fb.position(0); 
        return fb;
        }
        public void draw(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW); //1 
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_VertexData);  //2 
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_ColorData); gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            //3
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (m_Slices+1)*2*(m_Stacks-1)+2);
        }
        private void initLighting(GL10 gl) {
            float[] diffuse = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; //1
            float[] pos = {0.0f, 10.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f};   //2 
            gl.glLightfv(SS_SUNLIGHT, GL10.GL_POSITION, makeFloatBuffer(pos));  //3 
            gl.glLightfv(SS_SUNLIGHT, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, makeFloatBuffer(diffuse));   //4 
            gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);  //5 
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);  //6 
            gl.glEnable(SS_SUNLIGHT);   //7
            }
        }
```

And second is a render:
package com.example.solarsystem;

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class SolarSystemRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
private Planet mPlanet;
    public SolarSystemRenderer(boolean b) {
        mPlanet=new Planet(30,30,1.0f, 1.0f);
    }



    private float mTransY;
    private float mAngle;
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {


    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); 
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,(float)Math.sin(mTransY), -10.0f); 
    gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    mPlanet.draw(gl);
    mTransY+=.0f;
    mAngle+=.4;
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) //11
    {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);   //12
        float aspectRatio;
        float zNear =3.2f;
        float zFar =1000; 
        float fieldOfView = 30.0f/57.3f;    //1 
        float size;

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
        aspectRatio=(float)width/(float)height; //2 
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //3 
        size = zNear * (float)(Math.tan((double)(fieldOfView/2.0f)));   //4 
        gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size /aspectRatio,  //5
        size /aspectRatio, zNear, zFar);

    }
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) //15
    {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);   //16
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST); //17
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); 
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); 
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH); 
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthMask(false); 
        initGeometry(gl);
        initLighting(gl);

    }


}
```

So in surfaceCreated method i have mistake in initialization   initGeometry(gl);
            initLighting(gl); 
    Also if i cut my initLighting method from first class  to render class i get mistake on initialization makeFloatBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with this part of the book.

Try commenting out a couple of lines in the onSurfaceCreated method in the renderer:

initGeometry(gl); - because there is no method defined for this in the code.

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); - Not sure what the problem with this line, but commenting this one out made the whole thing work as described in the book.